# Error deploy Azure kubernetes ingress with static IP

Tags: azure, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Good guys
Let's see if someone can help me.
I have configured Azure Kubernetes (AKS) in version 1.13
I am trying to create an Ingress with static IP, but it is impossible for me.

I am use kubectl create -f static-ip-svc.yaml

```
#File

apiVersion: v1

kind: Service

metadata:

  name: nginx-ingress-lb

  labels:

    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx

    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

spec:

  externalTrafficPolicy: Local

  type: LoadBalancer

  loadBalancerIP: 40.121.219.126

  ports:

  - port: 80

    name: http

    targetPort: 80

  - port: 443

    name: https

    targetPort: 443

  selector:

    # Selects nginx-ingress-controller pods

    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx

    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

and show error:

> Type     Reason                      Age               From
>   Message   ----     ------                      ----              ---- 
>   -------   Normal   EnsuringLoadBalancer        8s (x4 over 43s)  service-controller  Ensuring load balancer   Warning 
>   CreatingLoadBalancerFailed  7s (x4 over 43s)  service-controller 
>   Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed to ensure load
>   balancer for service default/nginx-ingress-lb: timed out waiting for
>   the condition

Comment: check if your aks service principal has permissions to the `MC_xxx` resource group. also, check if the specified IP exists? and is in the `MC_xxx` resource group

Comment: I didn't see any update for the question and you also didn't accept it as the answer. So what is the purpose you come to SO?!

Answer (score 1):

For you, to create an Ingress with static IP, there are two ways to achieve it. But firstly, you need to know the info that resource groups for Azure Kubernetes service and its infrastructure.

The info is [Why are two resource groups created with AKS?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#why-are-two-resource-groups-created-with-aks) It explains that there are two resource groups, one for the Azure Kubernetes service itself and another for its infrastructure. So that there are two ways to create an Ingress with static IP.

Here the two ways:

1. Use the static IP which created in the group named `MC_xxxx_xxxx_location`.
2. Use the static IP which created in another group except for the group `MC_xxxx_xxxx_location`. In this way, you need to assign enough permission to the service principal of AKS, at least is "Network Contributor".

You get more details about "Use a static public IP address with the Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) load balancer" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip). I think you use the second way but you do not assign enough permission so that you got the error. Check the steps and try again following the steps.